# Delete AD b2c Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have created a ad b2c account for testing purposes. I have created a couple of them to test and demo it to some of my stakeholders. Now i am trying to delete it.

When i try to delete the ad account, it says "**there are application available that needs to deleted"**, there was only one application, but when i tried to delete ***i get the below message***.

[image]

Where should i go to delete the application, i tried manage.portal also,but the delete button is not enabled

Comment: Have you tried the usual guidelines for Azure AD deletion? The UI really could be better in my opinion, and I've often had to run a PowerShell script to delete every app and service principal that I can to be able to delete a directory.

Comment: There is a well-written article to delete Azure AD tenant in a proper way. 
 Did you check that @ https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureadb2c/2016/10/17/delete-b2c-tenant/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first remove the application in he b2c application and then try to delete the b2C AD, if you have not done this way(something gets corrupted), you might have to create the support ticket with MSFT.

**Additional checks**

You also can check  apps in `apps.dev.microsoft.com` if you have created one with your B2C user account.  Then that message will show in azure b2c application setting , you need go to `apps.dev.microsoft.com` and delete that app , you will find that application disappear in azure ad b2c application list after seconds .

Comment: I created the app using b2c account in portal.azure and apps.dev.microsoft.com does not have any application